# Dynamic creation of class instances from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create new instances of a class from a list.
Everything seems to work, but if I add a new value to the list and create a new instance of the `app` class, I get the `KeyError`.
I don't know if I have to completely abandon this path or if there is a solution to this.

```
class app:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app=None
    def start_app(self):
        return self.app.start()
    def stop_app(self):
        return self.app.stop()
    def return_app(self):
        return self.app

list=[123456,654321]
myapp = {k: app() for k in list}
print("1 my list: ",list)
print ("1 my app: ",myapp)
myapp[(list[0])].__init__
x=myapp[(list[0])].start_app
list.append(789000)
print("2 my list: ",list)
print ("2 my app: ",myapp)
myapp[(list[0])].__init__
print(myapp[(list[2])].start_app())
```

And the error:

```
1 my list:  [123456, 654321]
1 my app:  {123456: <__main__.app object at 0x7ff6916a53d0>, 654321: <__main__.app object at 0x7ff6916a5430>}
2 my list:  [123456, 654321, 789000]
2 my app:  {123456: <__main__.app object at 0x7ff6916a53d0>, 654321: <__main__.app object at 0x7ff6916a5430>}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/testCopia.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(myapp[(list[2])].start_app())
KeyError: 789000
```

Comment: The entry you appended to `list` doesn't have an app appended to `myapp`.

Comment: side note:  ``list` is a builtin and therefore shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Comment: The correct way to create instances of a `class` is to call *it* —i.e. `app()`— not  by calling its `__init__()` method explicitly (which btw is an initializer, not a constructor).

Comment: I strongly suggest you read and start following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `app` class gets created when you run app(), which you're only doing on the assignment to `myapp`. When you add a new key to `list` (you should use a different name, this is an existing type), you need to call app(), and maybe also add the new (kay, value) pair to myapp.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, after this line:

```
list.append(789000)
```

You need to add:

```
myapp[789000] = app()
```